# Installing Solr 5 on Debian 8

Tags: solr, debian

I followed the instructions on https://ctors.net/2015/07/14/solr5_java8_debian8.

As the *root*

First I installed Java 8:

```
mkdir -p /opt/java

wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2F; oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u45-b14/jdk-8u45-linux-x64.tar.gz"

tar xvf jdk-8u45-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /opt/java
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java 1
update-alternatives --set java /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java
```

Then I installed Solr:

```
 wget http://apache.belnet.be/lucene/solr/5.2.1/solr-5.2.1.tgz
 tar xvf solr-5.2.1.tgz
 ./solr-5.2.1/bin/install_solr_service.sh solr-5.2.1.tgz
```

But the installation ends up with the following error message:

```
 solr.service - LSB: Controls Apache Solr as a Service
 Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/solr)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2015-11-18 02:29:36 TMT; 5s ago
 Process: 1679 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/solr start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

 Nov 18 02:29:36 solrhost su[1681]: Successful su for solr by root
 Nov 18 02:29:36 solrhost su[1681]: + ??? root:solr
 Nov 18 02:29:36 solrhost su[1681]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user solr by (uid=0)
 Nov 1`enter code here`8 02:29:36 solruser solr[1679]: This script requires extracting a WAR file with either the jar or unzip utility, please install these utilities or con...assistance.
 Nov 18 02:29:36 solrhost su[1681]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user solr
 Nov 18 02:29:36 solrhost systemd[1]: solr.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
 Nov 18 02:29:36 solrhost systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Controls Apache Solr as a Service.
 Nov 18 02:29:36 solrhost systemd[1]: Unit solr.service entered failed state.
 Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
 Service solr installed.
```

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Comment: Can't you just use https://hub.docker.com/_/solr/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my colleague to have a look at the issue. He found two causes of error:

1) Insufficient memory (my box had 512 MB RAM memory). Additional memory resolved the issue.

2) Wrong jdk package, that is, wrong architecture choice. For different JDK packages look here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-se-6u24-download-338091.html.

Hope someday this will save someone else's time and nerves.

**As for Debian and Solr developers, it would be great if you could come up with simple receipt about how to install Solr 5 under Debian 8. For example, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-solr-5-2-1-on-ubuntu-14-04.**

Comment: Following https://gist.github.com/hvwaldow/67fecf80a9790b5c9153 made it for me ...

1. Install jessie backports deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main
2. Install openjdk-8-jre-headless
3. Run the Solr installer

Answer (score 6):

solr needs unzip to work. Install unzip if it isn't available on the system.

```
apt-get install unzip
```

It should fix the problem.

Comment: Spot on! Missing  unzip package  and it needs lsof  also.  Thanks a ton @DNX